# How to enable debug in slf4j Logger?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

How to globally enable `debug` for all the `slf4j.Logger` objects?

Comment: slf4j is an API.  You need to configure the implementation ("binding") behind the API.

Comment: @PeterRader, struggling to recollect that after 5 years. Soz, mate.

Comment: Sorry to ping such an old question, but I just want to cross-link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple which I found useful for configuring slf4j-simple to do the above.

Answer (score 44):

Programmatically, with logback:

```
setLoggingLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG);
```

where

```
public static void setLoggingLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level level) {
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(level);
}
```

Comment: Does that only work if logback is your "backing" logging api? 

I thought slf4j was going to make a facility for this.

Comment: @roottraveller I don't think Tomcat uses logback by default.

Answer (score 17):

exists various capability to switch debug log on:
this [article](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.ru/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html) have good explanation all of those. to me good fit is:

**Using slf4j with Log4j logger**
create file *src/main/resources/log4j.properties*

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT
log4j.logger.deng=INFO
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure "log4j.logger.deng=INFO" isn't a valid option.

Comment: Actually, it is. It defines INFO as the level for all classes/Loggers under package `package deng;`. A more natural example line would be `log4j.logger.org.faceless.product.magic=INFO` with a reversed FQCN, which is more common.

Answer (score 12):

Pass the System Property -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG at your Java startup for the SLF4J Simple api

[image]

Comment: So strange that this is not mentioned in the official SLF4J documents.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using slf4j with springboot, you just need to set debug level in `application.properties`.

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

You also can set the specific part by setting `logging.group`.

Image that, if you have `com.pxample`, `com.example`, `com.dxample` in `src/main/java/` and you setting:

```
logging.group.mycustomgroup=com.pxample, com.example
logging.level.mycustomgroup=DEBUG
```

, then only `com.pxample`, `com.example` will show debug output for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use logback as the slf4j binding.

The default behaviour without an configuration file is to log all events at level DEBUG and above to System.out.  See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticConf for details.

Comment: "Use logback as the slf4j binding." I am a noob. Can you please tell me how to do this? My google fu is failing me atm.

Comment: Remove your current binding (see http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#where_is_binding) and put logback-classic in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to the `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.context=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j as the binding of slf4j you can crete a log4j.xml (or log4j.properties) file and add it to the classpath. An example could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For log4j

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">

<!-- ============================== -->
<!-- Append messages to the console -->
<!-- ============================== -->

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="web" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/web.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.idc.scd" additivity="false">
    <priority value="${log4j.category.com.mypackage}"/>
    <appender-ref ref="web"/>
</category>

</log4j:configuration>
```

by this cofiguration your all "com.mypackage" logs will be written in "web.log" file under catalina.home.

Comment: Can you please suggest an alternative logging library where I won't have to add XML configuration files, and where debug/info/error are all enabled by default?

Comment: along with xml Log4j  also provides java classes where you can add your log4jconfigurations.

Comment: I mean, is there a library that requires me to provide no configuration and has sane/expected defaults?

Comment: You can use java logging API which provides following log levels -SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample configuration I usually use to setup logging with logback.
Gradle dependencies (the same apply to Maven)

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
```

`logback.xml` configuration to be placed in the project's classpath (src/main/resources)

```
<configuration>

    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <!-- enable debug only on org.hibernate.SQL package -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

depends on what binding you are using... if e.g. it's log4j have a look at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html and its Configuration chapter

Comment: I'm using: slf4j-api with slf4j-simple