# How to change SLF4J SimpleLogger filename?

Tags: java, file-io, slf4j, system-properties

My Java application uses `SLF4J` which I have configured to use the `SimpleLogger` implementation and redirect log messages to a file. That is working fine.

How do I subsequently change the name of the log file?

I have tried changing the `LOG_FILE_KEY` property but it seems to have no effect. The log messages continue to be output to the original log file.

This is what I've done:

```
System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.LOG_FILE_KEY, Paths.get("new-filename.txt").toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the file path to your liking, one simply has to set the following property, either in a file named `simplelogger.properties` on the classpath (e.g. by placing such a file under the resources directory) or through a `-D` JVM startup option.

The property name and syntax is simply:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=your-file-path
```

See [in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14545138/1509695) for examples of providing a property through either of the two mentioned methods.

Comment: How can make SimpleLogger to read simplelogger.properties file from outside the classpath i.e. I want to put this properties file outside the artifact at some system path.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the answer with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16887899/820657) and looking at the source code for `org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger`.

The answer is you can't create a new log file as the logger properties are loaded only once - upon construction of the first logger instance. Subsequent loggers will use the same properties as the first one.