# Where can I find request and response logs for Spark?

Tags: jetty, spark-java

I have just started using Spark framework. And experimenting with a local server on Mac OS

The documentation says that to enable debug logs I simply need to add a dependency. 
I've added a dependency and can observe logs in the console.

The question is where the log files are located?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the [Spark example here](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#add-a-logger), you are only enabling slf4j-simple logging. By default, this only logs items to the console. You can change this programmatically (Class information [here](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html)) or by adding a properties file to the classpath, as seen in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple). Beyond this you will likely want to implement a logging framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), as [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) is designed to act as a facade over an existing logging implementation.