# how to configure kotlin-logging logger

Tags: logging, kotlin, kotlin-logging

For logging purposes in my Kotlin project I am using [kotlin-logging](https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging) which is really nice to use however I am missing a very central point: How can I configure the log level of the logger?

Per default it is set to info and I would like to set it to debug. As there is nothing about that on the Github page nor is there any method to set the level programmatically I had a look into slf4j as kotlin-logging is a wrapper around that.

Apparently I have to set a System Property like this:

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG
```

However I have no idea how to do this in Kotlin.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Setting log level is done per implementation. Kotlin-logging and slf4j are just facades for the underlying logging lib (log4j etc'). Which one do you use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> We do not have a way to change log level from slf4j api and we need to rely on implementation

By looking at the [`Logger`](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/Logger.java) interface of `slf4j`, you can see that it has `isLevelEnabled()` for all the levels, but not a setter. Therefore, setting the level is implementation specific and it is based on the underlying logging platform you use.

---

From your question it looks like you use `slf4j SimpleLogger` as the layer behind `slf4j`. For `SimpleLogger`, you can only change the log level through properties like you've already done.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple) for more information.

```
System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY, "TRACE");
```

> Please note that once the logger is created the log level can't be changed. If you need to dynamically change the logging level you might want to use log4j with SLF4J.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a way to do this at runtime. Buildtime would be good enough for this project.

Comment: Hi, I've read again the question and now I hopes it really answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

*I'm using kotlin-logging in a **Spring Boot** application.*

### What worked

Run application with

```
-Dlogging.level.com.mydomain.myapp=DEBUG
```

(Replace `com.mydomain.myapp` with the desired package namespace or `root` for all.)

Alternatively you can add the property to an *application properties* file

```
logging.level.com.mydomain.myapp = DEBUG
```

### What didn't work

- `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG`
- `-Dorg.slf4j.simplelogger.defaultlog=DEBUG`
- `--debug` (as one of the program options)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using using `kotlin-logging` on Android, the easy answer is: just use [slf4j-handroid](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/slf4j-handroid).

It's a simple fork of the (recently deprecated!) `slf4j-android`, but which doesn't inherit *delightful* behaviors like requiring system properties to be set *just so you can see your debug logs.*

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access `org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL_KEY`, this seems to be working with `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.6`

```kotlin
    System.setProperty("org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel", "TRACE")
```