# Lombok @Slf4j - log to file

Tags: java, logging, lombok

How to configure Slf4j from Lombok if I want log info to file?

Example what I want to get:

```
@Slf4j
public class ExampleClass {
   log.info("some info");
}
```

And I want to get this info to file.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on your slf4j implementation and has nothing to do with lombok. See for example [slf4j-simple thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple), if you want to use that as an implementation.

There's also longer [blog post](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.se/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html) about different slf4j implementations.

But no, there is no way to do that with lombok, as that is not directly related to slf4j *implementation*.