# Why isn't my log not output to a file by slf4j?

Tags: log4j, slf4j

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

My log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

However, if I change from "slf4j-simple" to "slf4j-log4j12", it works as below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I use slf4j-simple to be able to output to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4j.properties is the config used for log4j.

To config slf4j-simple, see [How to configure slf4j-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple)