# How to disable Javalin logging

Tags: java, logging, kotlin, javalin

I'd like to turn off this logging under Javalin:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @850ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Starting Javalin ...
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Listening on http://localhost:8003/
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Javalin started in 334ms \o/
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Starting Javalin ...
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Listening on http://localhost:6667/
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Javalin started in 7ms \o/
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Stopping Javalin ...
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Javalin has stopped
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Stopping Javalin ...
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Javalin has stopped
```

... but Javalin does not seem to have a way to turn these logs off. Is there a way? thanks

Comment: Regarding your edit: it isn't "info about setting sl4f log level", it's info about setting **slf4j-simple** log level. Other implementations would need to be configured differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javalin uses [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) for logging (you can even see the class name `Slf4jLog` in the first message). This is an abstracton which can work with many different actual implementations, so the first step is to find which one your project uses. List the dependencies ([Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html)) and look for `slf4j-<something>` (except `slf4j-api`) or `logback-classic`. Then look at https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping for the one you found and find how to configure it to set to a higher level than `INFO`.

E.g. if you followed

> Javalin does not have a logger included, which means that you have to add your own logger. If you don’t know/care a lot about Java loggers, the easiest way to fix this is to add the following dependency to your project:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
>     <version>1.7.26</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

from the Javalin documentation, see [How to configure slf4j-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23391374/819651).