# How to turn off debug mode log of wicket

Tags: wicket

When I run program console show hundreds of lines of logs while rendering a page.
How to hidden this log?

```
16:52:01.581 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909148 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.581 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909148]]
16:52:01.582 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909148]]
16:52:01.583 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909149 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.590 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909149]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909149]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909150 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909150]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909150]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909151 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.591 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909151]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909151]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909152 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909152]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909152]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer - Add wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909153 to [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - Begin render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909153]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_relative_path_prefix_1623909153]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = body]]
16:52:01.592 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Component - End render [Page class = --------------, id = 0, render count = 1]
16:52:01.598 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.Page - ending request for page [Page class = ------------, id = 0, render count = 1], request org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest@4c322c5d
16:52:01.599 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - 'http-nio-8080-exec-2' released lock to page with id '0'
16:52:01.599 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer - 'http-nio-8080-exec-2' notifying blocked threads
```

[Log debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Nmf.png)

Comment: Hi, which version of Wicket are you running? Version 9 uses slf4j-simple as logger, so if you want to tune your  logging level you have to use the specific instructions for this framework:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544991/how-to-configure-slf4j-simple

Comment: I use wicket 8, notthing happen when I config same like this

Comment: What logging framework are you using then? And could you post the config of said logging?