# How to run java test in gradle in debug level

Tags: java, gradle

I built an app and build it with the gradle.
But I can't understand how to test in gradle in debug mode.

I enter:

```
gradle test -d > test.log
```

but I get only debug messages about building, not messages log.debug() from test.

log.info() messages I can see in builded test result's "Standart error" tab.
But how can I see [DEBUG] messages?

Comment: you need to set the  level of root Logger to DEBUG instead of INFO !! which logging framework are you using , if log4j then you need to set this in `log4j.properties file`

Comment: What kind of "app"? What are you using to log?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'm using sfl4j library.<BR>
It's simple java application.

Comment: @Neeraj could you answer me how can I edit this file.
Because I only have build.gradle with `dependencies {
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10'
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.8'}`

Comment: So now your question becomes [how-to-enable-debug-in-slf4j-logger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847458/how-to-enable-debug-in-slf4j-logger)

Comment: @NeerajJain I'm not asking how programmatically do it using setLevel.
I'm asking about how can I say to gradle run java app with debug level. So I would see debug messages in reports without changing code

Comment: @DavidLevesque
I use org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.8
<pre>  
in code:  
`private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchEngineService.class);`  
`public void testSomething() {`  
`log.debug("hello");`</pre>

Comment: @DavidLevesque I have `dependencies { compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10' compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.8'}` so I'm using java.util.logging

Comment: @wazz given your dependencies (org.slf4j), you're NOT using java.util.logging

Comment: @roomsg That's also what I thought first, but after verification `slf4j-jdk14` is actually the binding to use`java.util.logging`. See: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Comment: @DavidLevesque Hmm, I didn't know the slf4j-jdk14, till today ;-) Thx for clarifying, taking back my previous comment...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to set the log level programmatically, you can setup a configuration file for java.util.logging. You can find detailed instructions [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html).

See the property `"logger".level`. Set it to FINEST to log everything.

Answer (score 1):

1. slf4j is only an api, you need as well an implementation
2. Suggest to use logback-classic as implementation, by adding it in your gradle build file as a testRuntime dependency. Ref: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

That should do the trick. If you need more control, you can tweak logback by providing a logback(-test).xml. Ref: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html