# Can I enable DEBUG log level of a spring boot application with a VM property?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'd like to enable DEBUG log level of my spring boot application.
Like mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74678907/8315843, it's possible by modifying `application.properties` and rebuilding, repackaging and redeploying.
Is it possible to do the same by just changing a command line option such as a VM property and restarting ?

I use slf4j logging with code such as this :

```java
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

Please note, I'm not talking about the spring boot framework log level that can be set with a `--debug`, but the log level of the application that uses its `org.slf4j.Logger` and its own calls to `logger.debug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a VM property, but a command-line option :

```
--logging.level.root=debug
```

Comment: Any other way to specify a Spring Boot environment property (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)) will also work. E.g. `-Dlogging.level.root=debug`